# How to get events from a page with the new facebook graph api v2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

Earlier, this would give back a list of events:
**clubversuz/events**

Now it gives back an empty array called 'data'.

Ok..they say that now you should explicitly declare the fields in a request, so I tried that too with this, but it return nothing either. **The clubversuz id is used below:**

`8261409764/events?fields=end_time,start_time,timezone,id,name`

Does anyone know how to go further?

P.S. I just started with this API and yesterday I was glad: I could get events.

Now, one day later, it has been broken by changes from fb. Is this how it's going to be with the fb API, Create something, break, repair? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behaviour is still working if you explicitly provide the API version to be v2.3:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/8261409764/events?access_token=

When you use v2.4 in the above call, it's not returning any events. This might actually be a bug; can you create a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)?

Comment: I created a bug report at [https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/443054055873667/](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/443054055873667/)